# Determine whether it is true that this summation is zero for some increasing sequence of non-negative integers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence

**Question:**

> Consider the a strictly increasing sequence of **non-negative** integers $\{a_n\}$ and $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$, is it true that for any $\theta$, $\exists$ some $\{a_n\}$ s.t. the following sum over a finite branch of that sequence is zero or the infinite sum is zero?
> $$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\begin{pmatrix}\cos(a_i\theta)\\\sin(a_i\theta)\end{pmatrix}=0$$

**Attempt:**

I tried to use Chebyshev polynomial that I self-studies before to expand the summation like this
$$
S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor a_i/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2j}(\cos^2(\theta)-1)^j\cos^{n-2j}(\theta)\\
\sin(a_i\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I didn't expand the $y$-component because it seems to me that Chebyshev polynomial makes things even worse despite that it connects the summation to combinatorics in some sense...... Anyway, I'm not sure how to proceed further......

For $\theta=\frac{\pi}{n}$, $n\in\Bbb N$, this is true because the sequence $\{2^i\theta\}$ makes the summation a geometric series
$$\sum_{j=1}^ne^{i(j-1)\theta}=\sum_{j=1}^ne^{i(j-1)\frac{2\pi}{2n}}=0$$
but what about other $\theta$'s?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is $\binom\bullet\bullet$ a binomial coefficient?

Comment: @user Yes. That thing is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Could you show in detail how you proceed from binomial form to the exponential one?

Comment: @user Ah.. I didn't work out that special case from the binomial form. It's just a direct observation that when the sequence is a geometric progression and $\theta$ is some rational multiple of $\pi$, the summation can be reduced to a geometric series equal to $0$.

Comment: But I do not see in the question any other form from which you could start.